# Exception #0: Please upgrade your database

Tags: magento2

I just tried creating a basic module like in this [tutorial](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-create-a-module-in-magento-2/).

But when I try to request the controller, I get the error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Magestore_HelloMagento data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Magestore_HelloMagento data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0
#0 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#1 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#2 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#5 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#8 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#10 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#11 {main}
```

I tried executing `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, it was successful, but the error is still there.

Comment: are you create registration.php file??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `setup_module` Table

Find your module `Magestore_HelloMagento.`

Make sure `schema_version` & `data_version` should be same as per your current module.

Then run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

It will work

Comment: Magestore_HelloMagento data: current version - none that is the problem for this issue

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to programmatically fix this issue without requiring the database access?

Comment: i will check and tell you. is it possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the `Magestore_HelloMagento` from `setup_module` table name in database. 
Then run the command `bin/magento setup:upgrade`